# Write down the sample space of this experiment and give the distribution.

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

An urn contains $4$ red balls and $6$ black balls. You draw with replacement $2$ balls. 
a) Write down the sample space of this experiment and list $3$ events $A$, $B$ and $C$, whose intersection is not empty (i.e. $A ∩ B ∩ C= ∅$). 
b) Let $X$ be the random variable that counts the number of red balls among those extracted. What is its distribution?

For a) The sample space is $\Omega=\{W,R\}$ , so white and red (the set whose elements describe the outcomes of the experiment), correct? 
For the events in order to have intersection what should I consider? If I choose A={W,W}, B={R,R}, C={R,W} I think that should be an option, what do you think?

For b) I think that the distribution is a Binomial Distribution, it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), $\Omega=\{B,R\}^2=\{BB,BR,RB,RR\}$. An example of 3 events whose intersection is not empty would be
$$
A=\{BB\}, B=\{BB, BR, RB\}, C=\{BB,RR\}.
$$
$A=$ "*both balls are black*", $B=$ "*at least one ball is black*", and $C=$ "*both balls are of the same color*".

For (b), $\mathsf{P}(X=0)=\mathsf{P}(\{BB\})=(6/10)^2$,  $\mathsf{P}(X=1)=\mathsf{P}(\{BR,RB\})=2\times 24/100$, and so on. In general,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=k)=\binom{2}{k}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^k\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{2-k}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how did you calculate 4/10? It is the probability that both ball are black,  right? shouldn't be 1/4? :)

Comment: $4/10$ is the probability of drawing a red ball in a single trial.

Comment: you are right, thanks again!